# Display progress of lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm calling a lambda function getIDfromURL that takes around 1 hour to complete, as the dataframe contains almost one million lines. How can I monitor the progress of this lambda function?

```
df1['ID'] = df1.apply(lambda row: self.getIDfromURL(row['trade']), axis=1)

def getIDfromURL(self, URL):
       f = requests.get(URL)
       text=f.text
       temp=text[text.index("ID") + 10:]
       end=temp.index("\r\n")
       ID=temp[0:end-1]
       ID=ID.replace('"', '')
       return (ID)
```

Comment: You can't, really. If you made it a non-`lambda` function you could do some logging in it.

Comment: Why can't you display progress from within getIDfromURL()?

Comment: @jonrsharpe well, technically, in Python3, you could: `lambda x: x if not print('progress') else None`. Which should never be done in real code, ever, of course.

Comment: @timgeb please mail your Pythoning license back to GvR ;o)

Comment: @jonrsharpe happy Christmas to you, too!